# How to perform a SQL query that orders by a column of type JSON?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii

I am using a POSTGRESQL database and I need to order by a column that is of type JSON. This is the error I get:

```
ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type json
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "field" "t" ORDER BY "t"."brand" LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to order by JSON data type?  Any suggestion of a work around?

Table field:

- field_id  INT
- name  TEXT
- type  INT
- brand  JSON

Here is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM "field" "t" ORDER BY "t"."brand"';      
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$result = $data->queryAll();
```

Comment: What order do you want them to appear in? There is no obvious reason for `{"foo":"bar"}` to come before or after `{"answer":42}`, which is why Postgres doesn't have an ordering built in.

Comment: post your table description. and php code you have written.
As well as the JSON String.

Comment: I updated to include code.  My brand data has data like ["1","2"] or  ["3"].  I want to order by data.

Comment: @albertski That still doesn't explain what the order would be - which should come first of those two examples, and why? What about `["2","4"]` and `["3"]`, or are those impossible? Also, if you are only ever storing arrays, you should probably use an array type (e.g. `int[]` or `text[]`), not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need json accessors for this. As of PG 9.2, none are built-in:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html

PG 9.3 will feature those that you'd need:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

In the meanwhile, you could write an accessor method in e.g. plperl, or install an extension:

https://github.com/theirix/json_accessors

Comment: Denis,
I am using PG 9.3.  Can you let me know what function I can use? It seems those are only for selecting the items but not ordering by.

Comment: I haven't tried, so not 100%, but based on the 9.3 docs I linked to it seems to be one of `t->'brand'` or `t->>'brand'`.

Comment: @Denis I think `brand` is the name of the column, not a field inside the JSON.

Comment: Ah, ya. In that case, something like `brand->'name'` even. :-)